# When adding a New Org via the Add Relationship link, why does it fail if the relationship uses a sub-type

Tags: relationships, contact-types, sub-types

Scenario is this. If you have a RelType of Indiv (A) and Org subtype x (B), then when you get offered the New Organisation option, it creates the new record as an Org (standard) and hence the Relationship Type is then not valid.

> 1 invalid relationship record
> 1 relationship record was not created due to an invalid contact type.

How to fix?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is fixed if you go to civicrm/admin/uf/group/field?reset=1&action=browse&gid=5 (ie the Admin > Customise > Profiles > Reserved Profiles > New Organisation

and add a field of type Contact > Contact subtypes

then when you use the Add Org via the Add Relationship button, you can select the relevant sub-type